# Loop an animation and then stop

Tags: jquery, loops, animation

I am trying to make a logo flicker like a neon sign and then stop in the "on" version of the logo. I'm using this function to animate the logo and give it the neon effect:

```
// make logo glow
var $FlickImg = $('.logo img'), c = 0;

(function loop(){
  var time = ~~(Math.random()*600) + 1;
  $FlickImg.delay( time ).fadeTo(30, ++c%2, loop);
})();
```

The thing is that I want it to stop after looping X number of times (say, 10). I have tried with an interval but what that does is stopping the animation for X second and then it starts. I want the opposite: the animation should start when loaded, and stop after, say 10 seconds, or 10 loops.

Comment: if you're gonna go with a counter rather than @T.J. Crowder's suggestion, then bare in mind that your `c` variable already acts like a counter so you don't need to create a new one as all the current answers suggest.

Comment: I'm going with @T.J. Crowder's suggestion. :) Is great.

Comment: @BYossarian: Or even if he/she *is* going with my approach, come to that, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the great things about jQuery's animations is that they queue up, so:

```
(function(){
  var i, time;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      time = ~~(Math.random()*600) + 1;
      $FlickImg.delay( time ).fadeTo(30, ++c%2);
  }
})();
```

That will queue 10 iterations of the animations, which occur in order. Note that we don't need to use the callback, nor do we need to give the function a name (which is good, because IE8 gets that construct — which is called a *named function expression* — wrong; [details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html)). Or you could even get rid of the function entirely, although it's nice for scoping.

Answer (score 1):

For 10 iterations, you could use an iteration variable:

```
var logo_loop_iterations = 0;
(function loop(){
  if (++logo_loop_iterations == 10) return;
  var time = ~~(Math.random()*600) + 1;
  $FlickImg.delay( time ).fadeTo(30, ++c%2, loop);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a counter-variable to your script:

```
var $FlickImg = $('.logo img'), c = 0;
var count = 0;

(function loop(){
  if (count==10) return;
  count++;
  var time = ~~(Math.random()*600) + 1;
  $FlickImg.delay( time ).fadeTo(30, ++c%2, loop);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var Count = 0;
var myVariable= function(){
     if(Count <= 10) {
          Count++;
         var time = ~~(Math.random()*600) + 1;
  $FlickImg.delay( time ).fadeTo(30, ++c%2, loop);
     } else {
          clearInterval(myVariable);
     }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(myVariable, 10000);
});
```